# Validate rows in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my application I have a very large `DataGrid` with several `DataGridTemplateColumn`s. In the resources of the `DataGrid` there is a style for the `DataGridRow`s. This style looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDirty}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="AttachedProperties:DataGridExtensions.FocusOnEditingColumn" Value="{Binding IsEditing}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In my `ViewModel` I'm subscribed to the `PropertyChanged`-Event of the DataObjects which are contained in the ItemsSource of the `DataGrid`. So if the PropertyChanged-Event is called and the propertyname equals "IsEdit" I'll do some validations for all rows in the `DataGrid`. Therfor I'm using the following method:

```
private void CheckConsistence()
{
    foreach (Module module in SelectedGroup.Modules)
    {
        string currentTarget = ResolveTargetPath(module);

        foreach (Module toCompare in SelectedGroup.Modules.Except(new[] { module }))
        {
            string toCompareTarget = ResolveTargetPath(toCompare);

            if (string.Compare(currentTarget, toCompareTarget, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                module.IsInvalid = true;                
                ValidationAdvices.Add(new ValidationAdvice("Duplicated path"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the IsInvalid-Property in the Module-Object is set to true I change the Error-Object. A part of the Module-Object looks like:

```
public class Module : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private bool isEditing;
    public bool IsEditing
    {
        get { return isEditing; }
        set
        {
            isEditing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => IsEditing);
        }
    }

    private bool isInvalid;
    public bool IsInvalid
    {
        get { return isInvalid; }
        set
        {
            isInvalid = value;

            if (isInvalid)
            {
                error = "Error";
            }
            else
            {
                error = null;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged(() => IsInvalid);
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Error);
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }

    private string error;
    public string Error
    {
        get { return error; }
    }
}
```

My `DataGrid` has a `RowValidationErrorTemplate` which looks like:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RowErrorTemplate" TargetType="Control" x:Shared="False">
    <Grid ClipToBounds="False" Panel.ZIndex="10000">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adornedElement"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Height="16" 
               Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApp.UI.Resources;component/Graphics/Error_16x16.png"
               ToolTipService.IsEnabled="True"
               ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
               ToolTip="{Binding Converter={converters:ModuleValidationErrorConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My problem is now if two rows have the same path both rows should be displayed as error-rows. But only one row will get the errortemplate and the red-background defined in the Style for the `DataGridRow`. The call of `ValidationAdvices.Add(new ValidationAdvice("Duplicated path"));` is done for each row. What do I have to do so that every row gets the validationerrortemplate?

I also have set the `DataGrid.RowValidationRules` like:

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```